# Is there a way to hide the URL bar in Edge kiosk mode or to keep the finish button up

Tags: url, microsoft-edge, kiosk-mode

I have to do a kiosk computer for all administration purpose (taxes, credit card etc..)

After testing openkiosk that was not stable keep rolling back
I try porteus-kiosk but horrible to configure and no way to came back to the homepage with a button

After some research I found that is possible to config edge in kiosk mode with a special account and it's perfect because you can't do anything else than browser through the administration ui I made and there is a special button that finish the session and remove all cookies, login.

But the URL search is still up and I don't want that.

So is there a way to remove it? Or if I put the fullscreen mode is there a way to keep the special button?

Comment: [Windows 10 now includes a kiosk mode (Assigned access)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/kiosk-single-app) where you can choose edge as the kiosk app. After that you can choose a kiosk mode: 'As a digital sign or interactive display' OR 'as a public browser'. The later (public browser) shows URL bar & a 'end session' button, the prior (digital sign) doesn't show URL bar, in fact ANY of the browser buttons/UI making the site full-screen. I have the same desire as OP, however it appears you'll need to use a special 'kiosk browser' app

Answer (score 0):

> the url search it's still up and I don't want that So is there a way
>   to remove it

Do you mean you want to hide the address bar in Edge browser? If that is the case, you can find the Microsoft Edge Group Policy settings in the following location of the Group Policy Editor unless otherwise noted in the policy,and [disable Address bar drop-down list suggestions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/deploy/group-policies/address-bar-settings-gp):

```
  Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Microsoft Edge\
```

> if I put the fullscreen mode is there a way to keep the special
>   button ?

Please explain more detail about the special button, might be on your website, you could use layout template, and add the button in the template, Then, all the content page using this template.

Comment: Thanks for answering this quick ! the special button is just a defaut button add by microsoft edge when you're are in kiosk mode but it dissapear when you enter in full screen mode and I don't want that !